# Methods for ActiveRecord that not implies database or convert into Hash/Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model foo and in my index action I do:

```
@foos = foo.all
```

and now, on the view I want to know if this `@foos` contain a record whit `foo.id = whatever`

One method of do that is `@foos.exists?(id: whatever)`, but this method implies a bd query and I want avoid this.

Other method will be `@foos.collect(&:id).include?(whatever)` but this implies the conversion of all @foos into array, another case that I would avoid.

There are another ways to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I want also get this object not only know if exists, sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: In your `index` action put like `@foo_ids = Foo.pluck(:id)`.. and then check this `@foo_ids` inside the view..

Comment: I made an update of question, I am interested on check it on view, not on controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to check if the value exists in the array of results:

```
@foos.any? { |foo| foo.id == whatever }
```

This check will be performed on the result array without hitting the database again and without converting the array to another structure.

**UPDATE**

If you want the object returned, use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), like this:

```
@foos.find { |foo| foo.id == whatever }
```

This will return the first occurrence where `foo.id == whatever`.

Comment: Updated my answer with your request

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can use all methods of Enumerable class, I assume that ActiveRecord inheritate from Enmurable, it isn't?

Comment: Yes you can use all the Enumerable functions on arrays, hashes and any other class that includes the Enumerable module.